# Error TS2339: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I searched on Stackoverflow and on the web, I found this thread https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14813 but it does not solve my problem. I run into this error while compiling my code with `ng serve --watch`.

> Error TS2339: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'.

This part with `fd.entries()` triggers the error... any idea what is going on here?

```ts
onFileSelected(event) {
    const fd = new FormData;

    for (const file of event.target.files) {
        fd.append('thumbnail', file, file.name);

        const entries = fd.entries();
        // some other methods are called here e. g. upload the images

        for (const pair of entries) {
            fd.delete(pair[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I saw that there (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.iterable.d.ts) is some interface for `entries` but somehow this does not work for me.

**EDIT**

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the lib array of your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I've added my `tsconfig.json` on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) is not supported by all browsers. If you want to use the method anyways, and still have the target set to es5, you can [extend](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14537#issuecomment-285122839) the current interface

```
declare global {
  interface FormData {
    entries(): Iterator<[USVString, USVString | Blob]>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry may a noop question... Where do I place this interface? Just on the end of the file? I tried this but this did not solve the error. How do I have to implement this interface?

Comment: You can put it on top of the component class. If you are going to use this more often though, you can export it, and perhaps place it in a file of its own

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, when I placed it on the top of the component.. I still get the same error `error TS2339: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'.` Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps restart the cli, because it tends to cache the interface/interface changes

Comment: Nope, this didn't help, still seeing the same error, anyway many thanks for your help.

Comment: @webtobesocial I've updated my answer a bit, by using `declare global`. You can place this at the bottom of your `polyfills.ts`, and then you will be able to use the `FormData.entries()` everywhere in your code

Answer (score 106):

You need to add "dom.iterable" to your `lib` list in `tsconfig.json`, for example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable" // <- there you are
    ],
    // ...
}
```

Comment: and 'ng serve' again.

Comment: This is the only correct fix. In VSCode you'll need to run the command _TypeScript: Restart TS Server_ for it to pick up the new lib.

Comment: I have to add: `"downlevelIteration": true,` in my tsconfig.js as well.

Answer (score 10):

TypeScript isn't supporting it unless you are compiling to ES6.

```
"target": "es5"
```

If it is es6, then it will work.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. `new FormData().entries()` fails with `es6`. Did you test your solution?

Answer (score -5):

just use Object().entries(() => ) syntax.

Comment: smh i stg lol  .