# How to append a file to a FormData object?

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I'm trying to append a file, selected from a FileUpload control, to a FormData object:

```
fileUploadHandle(files) {    
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      this.fileContentFormData = files[0];
    }
}

console.log('file content - ' + JSON.stringify(this.fileContentFormData));
form_data.append('file', this.fileContentFormData);
form_data.append('username', 'Chris');
console.log('form data - ' + JSON.stringify(form_data));
```

I know my file is being retrieved because when I run 
`console.log('file content - ' + JSON.stringify(this.fileContentFormData));`
this is displayed:

> file content - {"file":{},"id":0,"icon":"doc","src":{"changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity":"data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAJJIeCgQ="}}

However, when I run 
`console.log('form data - ' + JSON.stringify(form_data));`
even the 'username' key-value pair isn't even being displayed.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong when appending to this FormData object? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Previously, it was not possible to inspect a `FormData` object with your debugger. The latest versions of Chrome and Firefox now support `FormData.entries()` to inspect `FormData`.

```js
// Create a test FormData object
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1', 'value1');
formData.append('key2', 'value2');

// Display the key/value pairs
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066875/how-to-inspect-formdata) for the source.

Comment: Hi, I used this on my code like so: `var pair of form_data.entries()`, but I'm getting a compile error: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'.ts(2339)

Comment: The `entries`method is not supported by all browsers. Check a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677868/error-ts2339-property-entries-does-not-exist-on-type-formdata

Comment: This error is in VS Code

Comment: I've used `alert(JSON.stringify(form_data));` & {} is being printed so there is nothing in form_data. I'm not sure how this answers my question.

Comment: I also tried `form_data.append('testAdd', 'testValue');` to see if I could add something to the formData, but it's still printing an empty object

Comment: Just create a fake interface for `FormData` that contains a `entries()` method as it's done in the other thread I gave you. It will correct your typescript error.