# 'entries' does not exist on type 'FileSystemDirectoryHandle'

Tags: typescript, npm

How can I make `npm run build` compile `FileSystemDirectoryHandle.entries()`?

I created a new project using:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

and added:

```
navigator.storage.getDirectory()
.then(filesystem => filesystem.entries())
.then(entries => {});
```

to `page.tsx::Home()`. `npm run build` then returns the error

```
Type error: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FileSystemDirectoryHandle'.
```

I tried setting `tsconfig.json` to

```json
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
```

according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377427/15927992) (with and without `downlevelIteration`), to no avail.

According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle/entries), the `entries()` method exists and it also works if I run `npm run dev` (which in my understanding skips any TypeScript checks).

**Update 1**

The typescript error can be ignored by disabling the typecheck like this:

```
(filesystem as any).entries()
```

Though, this is not really a "solution".

**Update 2**

Based on jonrsharpe's comment, I tried adding all possible library keys to `tsconfig.json`, but that does not help either:

```
"lib": ["es5", "es6", "es2015", "es7", "es2016", "es2017", "es2018", "es2019", "es2020", "es2021", "es2022", "es2023", "esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "webworker", "webworker.importscripts", "webworker.iterable", "scripthost", "es2015.core", "es2015.collection", "es2015.generator", "es2015.iterable", "es2015.promise", "es2015.proxy", "es2015.reflect", "es2015.symbol", "es2015.symbol.wellknown", "es2016.array.include", "es2017.date", "es2017.object", "es2017.sharedmemory", "es2017.string", "es2017.intl", "es2017.typedarrays", "es2018.asyncgenerator", "es2018.asynciterable", "es2018.intl", "es2018.promise", "es2018.regexp", "es2019.array", "es2019.object", "es2019.string", "es2019.symbol", "es2019.intl", "es2020.bigint", "es2020.date", "es2020.promise", "es2020.sharedmemory", "es2020.string", "es2020.symbol.wellknown", "es2020.intl", "es2020.number", "es2021.promise", "es2021.string", "es2021.weakref", "es2021.intl", "es2022.array", "es2022.error", "es2022.intl", "es2022.object", "es2022.sharedmemory", "es2022.string", "es2022.regexp", "es2023.array", "es2023.collection", "esnext.array", "esnext.collection", "esnext.symbol", "esnext.asynciterable", "esnext.intl", "esnext.disposable", "esnext.bigint", "esnext.string", "esnext.promise", "esnext.weakref", "esnext.decorators", "decorators", "decorators.legacy"],
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you can post the link to the documentation and then claim "the entries() method exists" without qualification.  Because it does not exist in all contexts.

Comment: That's part of `dom.asynciterable`, not `dom.iterable` - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/309fd3db81955ef7a4dd55a80e333b2b767717a7/src/lib/dom.asynciterable.generated.d.ts#L7.